# Laravel 7th version .env file if macOS

Tags: laravel-7

Where on macOS I can find .env file if I installed Laravel by `$composer`?
I've tried to find it by a simple search through the files but it gave me nothing

Comment: Turn on `Show Hidden Files`

Comment: ye I figured already but thx. can y make this comment like an answer to I mark y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on `Show Hidden Files`, then your `.env` will be visible.